# Why is jQuery .load() firing twice?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery, browser-state

I'm using jQuery 1.4 with jQuery History and trying to figure out why Firebug/Web Inspector are showing 2 XHR GET requests on each page load (double that amount when visiting my sites homepage (`/` or `/#`).

e.g. Visit [this](http://leslieowusuappiah.com/) (or any) page with Firebug enabled.

Here's the edited/relevant code (see [full source](http://www.leslieowusuappiah.com/wp-content/themes/leslieoa/src/(%5E_%5E).js.gz.php)): -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
        var hash = this.href; 
        if (hash.indexOf(window.location.hostname) > 0) { /* Internal */
         hash = hash.substr((window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/').length); 
         $.historyLoad(hash); return false;     
  } else if (hash.indexOf(window.location.hostname) == -1) { /* External */ 
   window.open(hash); return false; 
  } else { /* Nothing to do */ }
        });


 $.historyInit(function(hash) {
  $('#loading').remove(); $('#container').append('<span id="loading">Loading...</span>'); 
   $('#ajax').animate({height: 'hide'}, 'fast', 'swing', function() { 
    $('#page').empty(); $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');

    if (hash == '') { /* Index */ 
     $('#ajax').load('/ #ajax','', function() { ajaxLoad(); }); 
    } else {
        $('#ajax').load(hash + ' #ajax', '', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      switch (XMLHttpRequest.status) { 
       case 200: ajaxLoad(); break;
       case 404: $('#ajax').load('/404 #ajax','', ajaxLoad); break; // Default 404
       default: alert('We\'re experiencing technical difficulties. Try refreshing.'); break;
       }
      });
     }

}); // $('#ajax')
  }); // historyInit()


  function ajaxLoad() {
   $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
    $(this).remove(); $('#ajax').animate({height: 'show', opacity: '1'}, 'fast', 'swing');
    });
   }

    });
```

A few notes that may be helpful: -

- Using WordPress with default/standard .htaccess
- I'm redirecting `/links-like/this` to `/#links-like/this` via JavaScript only (PE)

  - I'm achieving the above with `window.location.replace(addr);` and not `window.location=addr;`
- Feel free to visit [my site](http://leslieowusuappiah.com/) if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example I originally posted above may have helped towards answering my own question...

On my live site .load() was nested within 2 levels of callbacks: -

```
$.historyInit(function(hash) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 500, 'swing', function() { \\ level 1
        $('#loading').remove(); $('#container').append('<span id="loading">Loading...</span>'); 
        $('#ajax').animate({height: 'hide'}, 'fast', 'swing', function() { \\ level 2
            $('#page').empty(); $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');

            if (hash == '') { /* Index */ 
                $('#ajax').load('/ #ajax','', function() { ajaxLoad(); }); 
            } else {
                $('#ajax').load(hash + ' #ajax', '', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    switch (XMLHttpRequest.status) { 
                        case 200: ajaxLoad(); break;
                        case 404: $('#ajax').load('/404 #ajax','', ajaxLoad); break; // Default 404
                        default: alert('We\'re experiencing technical difficulties. Try refreshing.'); break;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }); // $('#ajax')
        }); // $('html, body')
    }); // historyInit()
```

...moving the `if (hash)` statement outside callbacks brings me back down to 1 XHR GET for all pages (with `/` as the only exception).

Thanks again for trying to help Paulo.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you've answered your own question:

> "I'm redirecting `/links-like/this` to `/#links-like/this` via JavaScript only (PE)"

Comment: Nope, tried that. I'm doing this in plain JS on page headers like so: -

`<script type="text/javascript">l = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/'; ll=l.length; e=window.location.toString(); if(e.substr(ll, 1) != '#') { g = e.substr(ll-1,1) + '#' + e.substr(ll); window.location.replace(g); } </script>`

Commenting out `window.location.replace(g);` still has the same effect. Any other suggestions? 
Thanks anyway Paulo.